# Type.GetType("namespace.a.b.ClassName") returns null

Tags: c#, reflection

This code:

```
Type.GetType("namespace.a.b.ClassName")
```

returns `null`.

I have in the usings:

```
using namespace.a.b;
```

The type exists, it's in a different class library, and I need to get it by it's name given as string.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441680/how-can-i-retrieve-an-assemblys-qualified-type-name for info on how to get the assembly qualified name.

Answer (score 346, accepted):

`Type.GetType("namespace.qualified.TypeName")` only works when the type is found in either mscorlib.dll or the currently executing assembly.

If neither of those things are true, you'll need an [assembly-qualified name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx):

```
Type.GetType("namespace.qualified.TypeName, Assembly.Name")
```

Comment: Instead of using an assembly-qualified name you can load the assembly by name – `Assembly a = Assembly.Load("SomeLibrary");` – and then load the type by name from the assembly – `Type t = a.GetType("namespace.a.b.ClassName");`.

Comment: Perhaps you could like `typeof(SomeTypeInThatAssembly).Assembly.GetTypes().Where((t) => t.FullName == youFullName);` may save some hassle, eventually

Comment: Is it correct that you must specify `namespace.qualified.TypeName` and not only `TypeName` with this approach?

Comment: What if the Type is from generated wsdl from the server? This does not work for me. Do you have any idea why its not working? Thanks

Answer (score 198):

You can also get the type without assembly qualified name but with the dll name also, for example:

```
Type myClassType = Type.GetType("TypeName,DllName");
```

I had the same situation and it worked for me. I needed an object of type "DataModel.QueueObject" and had a reference to "DataModel" so I got the type as follows:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("DataModel.QueueObject,DataModel");
```

The second string after the comma is the reference name (dll name).

Comment: Is this a 'trick' or an actual method? I can't find this in documentation -_- . By the way, it ends my 1 week suffer! thanks

Comment: This is a much cleaner solution, I'd love to see if there are any pitfalls because of this.

Comment: The form used in this answer is also a fully qualified type name [according to the MSDN grammar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsftwz6(v=vs.110).aspx) (so it is not a _trick_). The form is `NamespaceTypeName, AssemblyNameSpec` where `AssemblyNameSpec` is the identifier of the assembly without any properties. Even though this answer is essentially the same as the accepted I assume that some people prefer this because it does away with some of the "noise" that the assembly properties introduce (e.g. `Version`, `Culture` `PublicKeyToken`). Fortunately, the properties are __optional__.

Comment: For nested types, you may need to do something like `AtlasKernelBusinessModel.AtlasConstants+ClaimCoverage+Status,AtlasKernelBusinessModel`

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem.  If you are trying to get TypeName from another assembly (say your solution has 2 projects and you are trying to get type of a class located in one project, from the other project, then you need to provide fully qualified class name and assembly name as comma separated as @AsafPala suggested.  See here same question I had and solution/explanation I added https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54681389/c-sharp-is-it-possible-to-get-actual-type-out-of-a-string-representing-that-type

Answer (score 97):

Try this method.

```cs
public static Type GetType(string typeName)
{
    var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
    if (type != null) return type;
    foreach (var a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    {
        type = a.GetType(typeName);
        if (type != null)
            return type;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is what actually worked for me. I had to tweak by adding a substring trim before the foreach loop, however, because I passed in an assembly-qualified name, and Assembly.GetType() only works if you exclude the assembly information.

Comment: Doesn't work for UWP because `AppDomain` isn't supported. Not sure of any alternatives.

Answer (score 31):

If the assembly is part of the build of an ASP.NET application, you can use the BuildManager class:

```
using System.Web.Compilation
...
BuildManager.GetType(typeName, false);
```

Comment: This is a fantastic answer and should be higher up on the page. Works like a charm and is dead-simple compared to the old way of getting the assembly's qualified type name.

Comment: @Graham it's old but it's essential and will never become obsolete or logically wrong. Each Type is contained in a specific assembly. We cannot identify a type with just its name without knowing about its container. Multiple types having one same name are possible. Although in some specific scope we do know for sure that a Type name is unique. Even the assembly itself needs a strong name (to be uniquely ensured) in many cases.

Answer (score 27):

```
Dictionary<string, Type> typeCache;
...
public static bool TryFindType(string typeName, out Type t) {
    lock (typeCache) {
        if (!typeCache.TryGetValue(typeName, out t)) {
            foreach (Assembly a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()) {
                t = a.GetType(typeName);
                if (t != null)
                    break;
            }
            typeCache[typeName] = t; // perhaps null
        }
    }
    return t != null;
}
```

Comment: this looks great, but what about generics using other assembly types?

Comment: @DemetrisLeptos (I know the comment is old - but other people may still be interested): use                 int index = typeName.IndexOf('\`');
                if (index > 0)
                {
                    typeName = _typeName.Substring(0, index + 2);
                }
Note that the `T` of the generic type is stripped off.

Answer (score 21):

if your class is not in current assambly you must give qualifiedName and this code shows how to get qualifiedname of class

```
string qualifiedName = typeof(YourClass).AssemblyQualifiedName;
```

and then you can get type with qualifiedName

```
Type elementType = Type.GetType(qualifiedName);
```

Comment: Am I missing something, don't you already have `elementType` if you do `typeof(YourClass)`?

Answer (score 17):

As [Type.GetType(String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx) need the [Type.AssemblyQualifiedName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx) you should use [Assembly.CreateQualifiedName(String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.createqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
string typeName = "MyNamespace.MyClass"; // Type.FullName
string assemblyName = "MyAssemblyName"; // MyAssembly.FullName or MyAssembly.GetName().Name
string assemblyQualifiedName = Assembly.CreateQualifiedName(assemblyName , typeName);
Type myClassType = Type.GetType(assemblyQualifiedName);
```

The Version, Culture and PublicKeyToken are not required for `assemblyName` that's why you can use MyAssembly.GetName().Name.

About [Type.GetType(String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx) :

> If the type is in the currently executing
>   assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name
>   qualified by its namespace.

Answer (score 11):

When I have only the class name I use this:

```
Type obj = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(t => t.GetTypes()).Where(t => String.Equals(t.Name, _viewModelName, StringComparison.Ordinal)).First();
```

Answer (score 8):

If it's a nested Type, you might be forgetting to transform a . to a +

Regardless, `typeof( T).FullName` will tell you what you should be saying

EDIT: BTW the usings (as I'm sure you know) are only directives to the compiler at compile time and cannot thus have any impact on the API call's success. (If you had project or assembly references, that could potentially have had influence - hence the information isnt useless, it just takes some filtering...)

Comment: Oh my! Do you know where this "+"-syntax is explained?

Comment: Protectorone I learnt it from https://www.amazon.com/Essential-NET-Common-Language-Runtime/dp/0201734117 IIRC, but that's a bit dated. Can I recommend https://www.amazon.com/CLR-via-4th-Developer-Reference/dp/0735667454/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1489044599&sr=1-1&keywords=clr+via+c%23 as a unerringly useful book for all .NET devs + includes this? Bottom line is that for Types, the CLR only has the namespace and the name - a nested type is not directly addressable. Hence a language, if it has a nested type concept gets to do what it needs (though in general most langs use a `+` separator)

Answer (score 5):

I am opening user controls depending on what user controls the user have access to specified in a database. So I used this method to get the TypeName...

```
Dim strType As String = GetType(Namespace.ClassName).AssemblyQualifiedName.ToString
Dim obj As UserControl = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(strType))
```

So now one can use the value returned in strType to create an instance of that object.

Comment: re-opening an epic-old topic... congratulations. However I have to downvote your answer because the TO actually knows the Typename and wants to get the type from it. Btw.: which method do you reference by <c>GetType(Namespace.ClassName)</c>, if its Type.GetType it´ll only work on types that are within your current executing assembly or mscorlib, but as TO sais none of these conditions applies.

Comment: @HimBromBeere
Thanks for the down vote. It is people like you that demotivate me to post my findings. I am still learning development and I am just trying to help others. And now you expect me to answer your question? By the way, I have answered the question correctly.
The class that I was creating an instance of resides in a different project and one has to use an AssemblyQualified name because of that. So please read the rest of the comments before downvoting.
"the type exists, it's in a different class library, and i need to get it by string name –  Omu"

Comment: @Stephan - Welcome to StackOverlow - its not a toxic place really. Honestly.

Answer (score 4):

If the assembly is referenced and the Class visible :

```
typeof(namespace.a.b.ClassName)
```

GetType returns null because the type is not found, with typeof, the compiler may help you to find out the error.

Comment: the type exists, it's in a different class library, and i need to get it by string name

Answer (score 4):

Try using the full type name that includes the assembly info, for example:

```
string typeName = @"MyCompany.MyApp.MyDomain.MyClass, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null";
Type myClassType = Type.GetType(typeName);
```

I had the same situation when I was using only the the namesspace.classname to get the type of a class in a different assembly and it would not work.  Only worked when I included the assembly info in my type string as shown above.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the comma is directly after the fully qualified name

```
typeof(namespace.a.b.ClassName, AssemblyName)
```

As this wont work

```
typeof(namespace.a.b.ClassName ,AssemblyName)
```

I was stumped for a few days on this one

Answer (score 2):

For me, a "+" was the key!
This is my class(it is a nested one) :

```
namespace PortalServices
{
public class PortalManagement : WebService
{
    public class Merchant
    {}
}
}
```

and this line of code worked:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("PortalServices.PortalManagement+Merchant");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me - I didn't want to build long library names, nor did I want to manually load libraries, so I programmatically found the library instead. Basically, I'm using the short name to find a match in GetTypes(), then I'm using that found construct to access the long name in the assembly. I really liked Marchino's LINQ implementation above, and wanted that to work for me, but I'm not good enough to work with two variables in LINQ statement :-)

```
    public static Type GetType(string type)
    {
        Type t = null;
        foreach (var a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            foreach (var s in a.GetTypes())
            {
                if (s.Name == type)
                {
                    t = a.GetType(s.FullName); 
                    if (t != null) return t;
                }
            }
        }

        return t;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6465096/365188) solution above seems to be the best to me, but it didn't work for me, so I did it as follows:

```
AssemblyName assemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\Bin\\AnotherAssembly.dll"));
string typeAssemblyQualifiedName = string.Join(", ", "MyNamespace.MyType", assemblyName.FullName);

Type myType = Type.GetType(typeAssemblyQualifiedName);
```

The precondition is that you know the path of the assembly. In my case I know it because this is an assembly built from another internal project and its included in our project's bin folder.

In case it matters I am using Visual Studio 2013, my target .NET is 4.0. This is an ASP.NET project, so I am getting absolute path via `HttpContext`. However, absolute path is not a requirement as it seems from [MSDN on AssemblyQualifiedNames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2exyydhb.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I cheated.   Since the types I want to create (by name) are all in In a dll I control, I just put a static method in the dll in the assembly that takes a simple name, and calls type.GetType from that context and returns the result.

The original purpose was so that the type could be specified by name in configuration data.   I've since change the code so that the user specified a format to process.   The format handler classes implement a interface that determines if the type can parse the specified format.   I then use reflection to find types that implement the interface, and find one that handles the format.   So now the configuration specifies a format name, a not a specific type.  The reflection code can look at adjacent dlls and load, them so I have a sort poor man's plug-in architecture.

Comment: Hi, I've downvoted by mistake, please edit your reply so I can undo it.

Answer (score 0):

Very late reply, but if anyone is dealing with this a decade later:

There is a very, very small chance that your class in Visual Studio has a `Build Action` set to "`Content`" instead of "`Compile`".

Click on your class in Solution Explorer, then look at the properties.

Check that Build Action is "Compile", not "Content".