# Type.GetType(string typeName) returns null

Tags: c#, class, reflection, activator, gettype

My code is

```
type = Type.GetType(key);
```

Key which i pass is a namespace qualified name .

My code is in BusinessLayer. I am creating a instance of DataAccessLayer. 
DataAccessLayer reference is added to BusinessLayer.

I am getting the error as **"Could not load type 'Catalyst.DAL.ExamDAO.CExamDAO' from assembly 'BusinessLayer, Version=1.9.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."**.

What should i do to specify explicitly thats the class is from DataAccessLayer  ?

Key vale is "Catalyst.DAL.ExamDAO.CExamDAO"

**Edit :**

My actual code is

```
public static object getClassInstance(string key, params  object[] constructorArgs)
        {
            string assemblyPath = null;
            string customClassName = null;
            DataSet objDataset = getAssemblyInfo(key);
            if (objDataset != null && objDataset.Tables.Count > 0 && objDataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                assemblyPath = objDataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ACA_ASSEMBLY_PATH"].ToString();
                customClassName = objDataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ACA_CLASS_NAME"].ToString();
            }

            Assembly assembly;
            Type type;

            if (assemblyPath != null && assemblyPath != string.Empty)
            {
                assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);
                type = assembly.GetType(customClassName);
            }
            else // if no customisation
            {
                type = Type.GetType(key);
            }

            object classInstance = constructorArgs == null ? Activator.CreateInstance(type) : Activator.CreateInstance(type, constructorArgs);
            if (classInstance == null) throw new Exception("broke");
            return classInstance;

        }
```

I am trying to load the default classes if there is no customization . Method is in BO . 
If i pass the key as namespace qualified names of any Bo type  it converts . But DAO type it wont

Comment: Why are you doing it this way instead of `new CExamDAO()`? if it is true that "DataAccessLayer reference is added to BusinessLayer" then should be no reason you can't use the `new` operator. Or if you really just want a type reference then `typeof(CExamDAO)`

Comment: Give us the text value of "key".

Comment: @Adam Ralph . Actually i need to switch between custom assemblies and default assembly . I dint put that code here .

Comment: @xanatos  i put the key value

Comment: possible duplicate of [Type.GetType("namespace.a.b.ClassName") returns null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825147/type-gettypenamespace-a-b-classname-returns-null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that whatever type it is will be within `DataAccessLayer`, then I'd get an `Assembly` reference as simply as possible, e.g.

```
 Assembly assembly = typeof(AnyPublicTypeWithinTargetAssembly).Assembly;
 Type type = assembly.GetType(namespaceQualifiedTypeName);
```

An alternative is to use `Type.GetType` with an *assembly-qualified* name, but that's more long-winded in terms of specifying the type name.

Comment: what is AnyPublicTypeWithinTargetAssembly , I am not getting access to this.Which assembly reference i need to use.

Comment: AnyPublicTypeWithinTargetAssembly is any public type withn target assembly. Just pick one type in that assembly that you will not remove later, and put it in the expression. Also if you know the name of the assembly you could use Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyName)

Answer (score 3):

If the type is not present in calling assembly you need to use the `AssemblyQualifiedName` to get it Type instance. To resolve your issue, you need set `key` value with `AssemblyQualifiedName` instead of `namespace qualified name`.

Comment: This is an important point, not mentioned in the selected answer: if the specified type is not from the calling assembly, the Assembly Qualified name needs to be used. It is not enough to just use the assembly name.

Answer (score 0):

If `CExamDAO` is a subclass of `ExamDao`, then the notation is (note the `+`):

```
Catalyst.DAL.ExamDAO+CExamDAO
```

The best thing you can do is create a CExamDAO directly and then take its `GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName` (for example in the debugger). Something like:

```
(new CExamDAO()).GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName
```

or (if you are sure where you need it its assembly is already loaded)

```
(new CExamDAO()).GetType().FullName
```

and then copy/paste it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Is your type public?
Internal classes can not be loaded from different assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

Or try this:

```
 private static object GetResultFromStaticMethodClass(string qualifiedClassName, string method)
 {
      Type StaticClass = Type.GetType(qualifiedClassName);
      MethodInfo methodInfo = StaticClass.GetMethod(method);
      object result = methodInfo.Invoke(null, null);
      return result;
 }
```

Use:

```
object result = GetResultFromStaticMethodClass(
    "Utilities.StringHelper,DaProject",
    "ToList"
);
```

This call the static method **ToList** in the **StringHelper** class, in the **Utilities** namespace, in the **DaProject** project (same assembly and project name).

If you need parameters, add them in the second parameter in the **methodInfo.Invoke(null, null)** call