# Reflection C# - GetType() Returns Null

Tags: c#, reflection, null

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Type.GetType(“namespace.a.b.ClassName”) returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825147/type-gettypenamespace-a-b-classname-returns-null)

I am trying to recieve the type of an object as follows:

```
Type type = typeof(Namespace1.SubFolder.Class);
Type type2 = Type.GetType("Namespace1.SubFolder.Class");
```

Why is type2 being returned as null and type being returned as expected? I wish to create a class from a string value selected by the user eventually.

Comment: if you look on the right side of this page, u see A LOT of similar answers, have you checked them?

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825147/type-gettypenamespace-a-b-classname-returns-null