# find the type of a model in controller T4 template

Tags: c#, t4

I am modifying T4 controller template of visual studio 2013. I need to find the type of a model class (e.g. Hospitalization model). Please also note that I have one project in the solution. `Hospitalization` class is defined in `namespace WebApplication2.Models`

what I did:

```
<#@ assembly name="C:\Users\noornayeem\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\bin\WebApplication2.dll" #>
...
<#@ import namespace="WebApplication2.Models" #>

....
<#+

void foo()
{
     string str ="WebApplication2.Models.Hospitalization, WebApplication2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null";
     Type typeModel = Type.GetType(str);

     //typeModel is always null here
}
#>
```

In the `foo()` function, I tried with `typeof(WebApplication2.Models.Hospitalization)`. This works. However, I want to get the type by using string name. Any hep will be appreciated.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825147/type-gettypenamespace-a-b-classname-returns-null). but it is not working.

Comment: What is the value of `typeof(WebApplication2.Models.Hospitalization).AssemblyQualifiedName` ?

Comment: WebApplication2.Models.Hospitalization, WebApplication2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Comment: Is it also null when you run the template in the debugger?