# Casting a String to a Type in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, casting, enums

To be specific. I need to cast a string to an enum. I have tried Type.GetType() but it doesn't seem to work in Unity or I need some complex assembly code. I know of ways to cast a Type to a string but not a nice method the other way around. I am using Unity and C#. I have looked at many answers here with no avail.

Side note : This wont be needed to answer if someone knows how to use an enum as as parameter. Again I scoured google but only found code that picks apart enums to send them or the answer no. Any light on this would be great also.

eg. `Load(enumType);`

Comment: Why it didn't work in the normal C# way, what have you tried exactly ? Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825147/type-gettypenamespace-a-b-classname-returns-null for example

Comment: In Unity it also requires an assembly parameter for some reason. Also It wont cast not native/system types. Im looking for a way more simple piece of code to cast my own way rather than use GetType. from what I have seen its not good in Unity with custom Types without a bunch of assembly searching ( slow)

Comment: I was using Type.GetType("Node.NodeType"); and it was giving me an error for a second paramter