# GetType from fully qualified type name not working

Tags: vb.net, types, fully-qualified-naming

```
Public Sub New(ByVal oldC As Control)
    Dim FQTN As String = oldC.GetType.FullName
    Dim t As Type = Type.GetType(FQTN)
    Dim newC As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(t)
End Sub
```

`FQTN` is returning the correct Type name, but `t` is `Nothing`. For instance, `FQTN = System.Windows.Forms.Panel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `FQTN`.

This works with the panel example you're looking for

```
Public Sub New(ByVal oldC As Control)
    Dim t As Type = oldC.GetType()
    Dim newC As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(t)
End Sub
```

Also, this is a duplicate of [Type.GetType("namespace.a.b.ClassName") returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825147/type-gettypenamespace-a-b-classname-returns-null)

Comment: Hm, for some reason I was thinking `CreateInstance` would be different by using FQTN. Not sure why I thought that.