# Type.GetType from string for attribute return null

Tags: c#, types, attributes

Why does

```
Type.GetType("System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.KeyAttribute");
```

return null?

Comment: Do you have `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` referenced?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825147/type-gettypenamespace-a-b-classname-returns-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need

1. Reference `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnonations.dll` as @Sinalr comment
2. Use the **full qualified assembly name**

How to find the qualified assembly name?

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.KeyAttribute).AssemblyQualifiedName.ToString());
```

Then you can get the type from the assembly name:

```
Type.GetType("System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.KeyAttribute, System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35");
```

Hope it helps.