# DeserializeObject Error: Value cannot be null

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I'm using the plugin `Newtonsoft.Json` in my xamarin.forms application for serializing and deserializing an object of typr `Form`

```
public class Form
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int id { set; get; }

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string title { set; get; }

    [JsonProperty("body")]
    public string body { set; get; }

    [JsonProperty("department_id")]
    public string department_id { set; get; }

    [JsonProperty("fields")]
    public List<FormField> fields { set; get; }
}

public class FormField
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int id { set; get; }

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string label { set; get; }

    [JsonProperty("inputtype")]
    public string inputtype { set; get; }

    [JsonProperty("key")]
    public string key { set; get; }

    [JsonProperty("item_order")]
    public int order { set; get; }

    [JsonProperty("required")]
    public bool isRequired { set; get; }

    [JsonProperty("enabled")]
    public bool isEnabled { set; get; }

    public CellCustom fieldObject { set; get;}


    public FormField()
    {
        fieldObject = CreateInstance() as CellCustom;
    }

    private object CreateInstance()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("Hura.Models.Cells." + inputtype));
    }

    public Cell createCell()
    {
        return fieldObject.createCell();
    }
}
```

here is the deserializing code

```
string str= @"{""id"": 17,""title"": ""testform"",""body"": ""null"",""department_id"": 5,""fields"": [{""id"": 28,""title"": ""null"",""inputtype"": ""text"",""key"": ""f1474532070512"",""item_order"": 1,""required"": true,""enabled"": true}]}";
Form tstfrm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Form>(str);
MainPage = new FillForm(tstfrm);
```

But when I run this code, it gives me the error `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type` even when I don't have any fields named "type" in my JSON object!

What is the problem in my code, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that the type `"Hura.Models.Cells." + inputtype` exists in your currently executing assembly or in mscorlib.dll. If it doesn't, you have to specify the assembly name. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825147/type-gettypenamespace-a-b-classname-returns-null).)

In your example code the requested type name is `Hura.Models.Cells.text` which doesn't exist and therefore returns a null to the type parameter of the `Activator.CreateInstance`.

Maybe a null check will be enough but it depends on how you want to deal with that kind of situation.

Comment: Your first answer before editing was the correct answer, Thank you vary much! The problem was in the classes namespace. I made a typo by mistake in the `inputtype` variable value and now it's working fine. You saved my live!! thanks.

Comment: I did a rollback of my edit to correctly reflect your situation. You're very welcome! Glad I could help you.  :-)  (And if my answer was helpful, you can of course upvote it too.)