# Using Class Library create Object of a class from main MVC application c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to instantiate an object of a class using Activator.`CreateInstance`. So, I have an ASP.Net MVC project under which i have a folder called Modal and under that i have one class `TestClass.cs`.

Now i have another Class Library project. So have i written the instantiation login inside one of the class of my Class Library project and copy the `.dll` file inside my main ASP.Net MVC project.

Now from my main project i requested to my recently add Class Library project to create an Object of the class by passing FullyQualified name of my class.

EX:

**ASP.Net MVC Project**

```
------------------------------
`
namespace MyProject.Modal
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public TestClass()
        {
        }
    }
}
`
```

### Class Library Project Code

`

```
namespace SpringNet.FactoryContext
{
   public class CreateInstance
   {        
     public Object GetClass(string FullyQualifiedName)
     {
        Object NewClassType = null;
        Type ClassName = Type.GetType(FullyQualifiedName);
        NewClassType = Activator.CreateInstance(ClassName);
        return NewClassType;
     }
   }
}
```

`

### Now i build my Class library project and added reference to my ASP.Net MVC Project and tries to create the object.

```
CreateInstance instance = new CreateInstance();
var NewObject = instance.GetClass("MyProject.Modal.TestClass");
```

After calling this i am getting exception

- `Type ClassName = Type.GetType(FullyQualifiedName);`

at this line only i am not able to get the type of class what i am requesting for.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to add reference to your class library project.

Comment: You can also load the assembly at runtime, then try to instantiate the type using  `Activator.CreateInstance(ClassName)`

Comment: My class library is a stand alone dll file. As i am already using dll in my main project and if i will tries to add the main project reference in my Class library then it will become circular refence.

Comment: You cannot or at least shouldn't make them both aware of each other. You should introduce third project that they both can can reference and communicate with each other through.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
namespace SpringNet.FactoryContext
{
   public class CreateInstance
   {        
     public Object GetClass(string assemblyName,string className)
     {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyName, className);
     }
   }
}
```

And then

```
 CreateInstance instance = new CreateInstance();
    var NewObject = instance.GetClass("MyProject", "MyProject.Modal.TestClass");
```

**Updated**: Why Type.GetType return null

[Type.GetType("namespace.a.b.ClassName") returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825147/type-gettypenamespace-a-b-classname-returns-null)