# Entity Framework get table by variable name

Tags: entity-framework, variables

I'd like to retrieve a table from a variable value. For example, instead of:

```
myContext.Customers.ToList()
```

I want to use something like:

```
var tableName = "Customers"
myContext.tableName.ToList()
```

Can anyone steer me in the right direction?
TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory you should be able to do something similar to this:

```
var eType = Type.GetType($"{EntityNameSpace}.{tableName}");
myContext.Set(eType).ToList();
```

Ref 1: [Type.GetType("namespace.a.b.ClassName") returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825147/type-gettypenamespace-a-b-classname-returns-null)

Ref 2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_DbContext_Set_System_Type_