# VB Type.GetType("") returns nothing

Tags: vb.net

I have this Enum type:

```
namespace foo.bar
{
  public enum MyEnum: byte
  {
...
  }
}
```

When I try to get its type, I use :

```
Dim t As Type = Type.GetType("foo.bar.MyEnum")
```

I get t = Nothing???!

Comment: Is it VB.NET or C#?

Comment: The Enum is declared in C#, 
but I need to get the type in a VB.NET class

Comment: You are not using a [fully qualified type name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/specifying-fully-qualified-type-names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Type.GetType("namespace.a.b.ClassName") returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825147/type-gettypenamespace-a-b-classname-returns-null)

According to that `Type.GetType(..)` only works when the type is found in either `mscorlib.dll` or the current executing assembly.

So you need to use:

```
Type.GetType("foo.bar.MyEnum,ClassLibrary1")
```

replace "`ClassLibrary1`" with the name of your library that contains the enum and it should then work.

Comment: Indeed my enum was in a different library which which caused the issue. Thx.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are missing the root namespace. Just get the type from the actual enum, this will give you the string value.

```
GetType(MyEnum).ToString()
```

From a quick example, I got.

```
Type.GetType("ConsoleApplication1.Module1+MyEnum").ToString()
```

Comment: Yes, `GetType()` (VB) is equivalent to `typeof()` C#.

Comment: I finally used 
Dim myBloodyEnumType As Type = foo.bar.MyEnum.MyValue.GetType()
which worked fine...
The funny thing is that if I use to string on this, I do get the "foo.bar.MyEnum" that I tried using in the first place....
Still quite puzzled...

Comment: @A.D. you might need to add the assembly name at the end

Answer (score 1):

Adding to other answers, here's another way to achieve what you need.

Say, your C# project has namespace `ConsoleNET` and produces `ConsoleNET.dll`. There you defined your enum:

```
namespace foo.bar
{
    public enum MyEnum : byte { One, Two }
}
```

Your VB.NET project references this C# project. You can investigate the types in it by loading this library for reflection only:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim asm = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad("ConsoleNET")
    Dim t = asm.GetType("foo.bar.MyEnum")
    If t Is Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine("t is nothing")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("t is not nothing")
    End If
End Sub
'Output: t is not nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others you are probably not using the fully qualified type name. I think you are missing the assembly specification. To get the type of you have to give the "assembly-qualified name":

> The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. See [AssemblyQualifiedName](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Type_AssemblyQualifiedName). If the type is in the currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name qualified by its namespace.

Thus in your case it will look something like the following:

```
Type.GetType("AssemblyName.Namesspace.EnumerationName")
```