# The given assembly name was invalid Type.GetType() not working

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)

I am getting an exception from C# in a simple program consisting of two classes, **Program.cs** and **AnotherClass.cs**. I want to use the static `Type.GetType` method in **Program.cs** to get `AnotherClass` as a class when given as a string for a more complex program. When I use the following code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Assembly a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        //Console.WriteLine(a.FullName);
        Type t = Type.GetType($"SmallTestingSimulator.{a.FullName}.AnotherClass");
        Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
    }
}
```

and an empty class in a different file but same namespace

```
class AnotherClass {

}
```

I get the error. How do I go about using Type.GetType() for another class in this project? Without using the assembly, it gives a NullReferenceException.

*Related Questions*

[Type.GetType("namespace.a.b.ClassName") returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825147/type-gettypenamespace-a-b-classname-returns-null)

Comment: `typeof(AnotherClass).AssemblyQualifiedName` to get the name of the type.

Comment: In my other program I only habe the name of the class as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's drill through the reflection that happens and figure it out:

```
Console.WriteLine(a.FullName);
```

writes

> ProjectAssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

To figure out what we need to send into `Type.GetType()`, we can just spit out the `FullName` of the type we're trying to get:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(AnotherClass).FullName);
```

and that should output something like:

> SmallTestingSimulator.AnotherClass

Then, your call to get the type could just run

```
var t = Type.GetType($"SmallTestingSimulator.AnotherClass");
```

This should work in most cases, unless you're doing something goofy with namespaces/assemblies.

Comment: This doesn't matter if "AnotherClass" is in a folder, correct?

Comment: So what you're saying is, the assembly qualifier doesn't matter to return the Class as a Type object?

Comment: Correct - the assembly qualifier is unnecessary there, and folder doesn't matter. The only thing that would make a difference is if `AnotherClass` is also in another namespace, in which case that would need to be specified (e.g. `$"SmallTestingSimulator.SubNamespace.AnotherClass"`).