# C# Type.GetType(string typeName) returns null

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, appdomain

I know it might look like a duplicate question, but I haven't found any that points to this specific situation.
I use AssemblyQualifiedName and I know the assembly is loaded in AppDomain.

This code returns null:

```cs
var type = Type.GetType(TypeName);
```

This code returns the type:

```cs
var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
var names = TypeName.Split(new[] { ',' }, 2).AsQueryable();
var type = assemblies.Single(x => x.FullName == names.Last().Trim()).GetType(names.First());
```

The `typeName` variable is *AssemblyQualifiedName*
The value is "testTransform, transform, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
[image]

### EDIT 06 Feb 2020

I found this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/556041 which states:

> If assemblies are not strong-named signed, only file names are used for loading.

And this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xslt-compiler-xsltc-exe?redirectedfrom=MSDN which states:

> You cannot generate signed assemblies with xsltc.exe.

Could it be that Type.GetType() doesn't work with unsigned assemblies?

### EDIT 12 Feb 2020

I signed the assembly and the behaviour didn't change.

### EDIT 13 Feb 2020

The whole code is too big to fit in. The context is, there's a parent software that can be configured to run third party assemblies. It creates a new AppDoamin to run the assembly. My code is a third party assembly running inside that application. TypeName is simply defined as a parameter accepting values from a configuration window:

```cs
[DisplayName("Type Name"),
Category("Transform"),
Description("Qualified Name For XSL Transform Type."),
ListBoxItemProvider(typeof(TypeListGenerator), nameof(RootDirectory), nameof(AssemblyFile)),
Editor(typeof(ListBoxEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
public string TypeName { get; set; }
```

Comment: As per the answer published here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1825156,
you also need provide assembly name. Did you try this?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm passing to GetType

Comment: hi, please write full code that declared TypeName.