# Returns null when executing Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary`2[System.String,System.String]");

Tags: c#, types, gettype

I'm trying to get the type of the stringified object type of SortedDictionary but it always returns a null value. However, it works with Dictionary.

It works:
`` Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]"); ``

Doesn't work and always return a null value:
`` Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary`2[System.String,System.String]"); ``

Why and how should I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type.GetType(“namespace.a.b.ClassName”) returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825147/type-gettypenamespace-a-b-classname-returns-null)

Comment: No, cause I can use SortedDictionary object as usual

Comment: If you use [`assembly qualified name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Type_AssemblyQualifiedName) then you will be able to get type of the `SortedDictionary<string, string>` by its name. Here is [sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vFldW7).

Comment: What version of .NET framework do you use?

Comment: It solved my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method [`Type.GetType(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Type_GetType_System_String_) can return type by its name only if this type is located either in the current executing assembly or in the `mscorlib.dll`. For other types it requires [`assembly qualified name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Type_AssemblyQualifiedName) to be specified.

[`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) is located in the `mscorlib.dll` (for `.NET Framework`) therefore

```
Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]");
```

was able to return its type.

[`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) is located in the `System.dll` therefore

```
Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary`2[System.String,System.String]");
```

returned `null`.

To get type of the `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` we need to specify its `assembly qualified name`:

```
Type.GetType(
    "System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary`2[" +
    "[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]," +
    "[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]" +
    ", System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");
```

Here is [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4UzgAe) that shows it.