# Parse the fully qualified string representation of an enum, including namespace/type

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm aware of Enum.TryParse(), but it doesn't handle the namespace and type being present in the string. Say I have the following enum:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    enum MyEnum
    {
        One,
        Two,
        Three
    }
}
```

I can't use `Enum.TryParse("MyNamespace.MyEnum.One", out MyEnum xxx)`. It returns false because "MyNamespace.MyEnum.One" is not recognized.

`Enum.TryParse("One", out MyEnum xxx)` works fine.

Is there a way I can do that with any other mechanism in .Net?

Comment: You need to put it in a class. Can you just add the `using MyNamspace;` where you need to use it?

Comment: Even if you do "MyEnum.One" it doesn't work. This value you need to parse is just the constant. You can't change that.

Comment: I'm only guessing but maybe the namespaces and containing class names are only visible to the compiler and not to the runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple approach would be to write a small utility method to just parse the token after the last period character:

```
public static class EnumHelper
{
    public static bool TryParse<TEnum>(
        string value,
        out TEnum result) where TEnum : struct
    {
        string toparse = value;

        int loc = value.LastIndexOf('.');
        if (loc > 0)
        {
            toparse = value.Substring(loc + 1);
        }

        return Enum.TryParse(toparse, out result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool! That was actually my fallback if nothing else worked.

Answer (score 0):

`Enum.TryParse` expects you to know which type of enum you are expecting;

```cs
Enum.TryParse(typeof(MyEnum), "One", out var value);
```

You could try to parse a type from a string first;

```cs
var type = Type.GetType("MyNamespace.MyEnum");
Enum.TryParse(type, "One", out var value);
```

Comment: I've tried your GetType idea but that didn't pan out (returns null).

Comment: Ah, right. That method works differently than I remembered (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825147/type-gettypenamespace-a-b-classname-returns-null)