# How to get a product key token from a library file programatically?

Tags: sharepoint, assemblyinfo

I am creating a SharePoint solution project that will install the Telerik dll files into the GAC and write the appropriate lines into the webconfig upon feature activation. My question is, is there a way to get the product key token, version, and culture info of a dll programatically. I have used the System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() before to get the embedded resources, such as a javascript file, and add it to the appropriate folder. Would this be the same way to get the dll file, and if so what would I do to get the assembly info of an embedded assembly? Thanks for any direction.

Answer (score 0):

See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441680/how-can-i-retrieve-an-assemblys-qualified-type-name).

Out of curiosity, where in your web.config are you adding references to Telerik DLLs? I recently did a project that uses the Telerik Silverlight controls. While I had to configure the web.config to support the .Net 3.5 framework, I did not have to add anything specifically for the Telerik DLLs as their controls were all wrapped within my custom Web Parts.

Comment: Being that this is a SharePoint app I need to write the safe controls, http handlers, controls, and add the assembly reference to each web config farm wide. That is why I'm using a WSP to do this.